# Do God and Satan Celebrate Earthly Triumphs?

Tags: nature-of-god, satan, temptation, abraham

Many people talk about "A Never-Ending Battle Between Good and Evil".

The Bible mentions specific interventions by God and Satan to influence earthly events.

- ['The Binding of Issac'](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_of_Isaac) stands out in my mind as an example of God's intervention.
- And ['The Temptation of Christ'](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temptation_of_Christ) stands out in my mind as an example of Satan's intervention.

My question:

- Do God and Satan celebrate earthly triumphs?

For instance:

- Did God celebrate after Abraham did as He commanded him to do after 'The Binding of Issac'?
- Would Satan have celebrated if Jesus succumbed to his temptations in the desert?
- Does either continue to celebrate as we live life on planet Earth?

Answer (score 5):

As the word 'celebrate' implies satisfaction or joy, I don't think we can properly say the Devil 'celebrates' in any thing that he falsely perceives as accomplishing his hate. As the Devil in enraged by cruel ambitions, he can find no real satisfaction or joy. Rather all his efforts would be understood better as an energetic and powerful 'writhing in agony.' As the scriptures do not unveil the secret and loathsome works of darkness, any further speculation on how the Devil feels or perceives things falsely would be out of place. We only know he is suffering death.

God on the other hand can be said to rejoice in all his works, taking pleasure in all the good he accomplishes. It is the nature of good to take pleasure in Good and to the degree of that goodness achieved the more God, in a sense, 'celebrates it.' God's rejoicing is not only in Himself but even a believer's joy could be said to be God's joy in the heart of man. The kingdom of God includes joy because by entering it we have communion with God's celebration of all he does and all he is:

> For the kingdom of God is not a matter of eating and drinking, but of righteousness, peace and joy in the Holy Spirit. (NIV Romans 14:17)

This joy, when eminent with respect to a wonderful work where God takes special joy, is often accompanied by illustration in the celebration of angels:

> I tell you that in the same way there will be more rejoicing in heaven over one sinner who repents than over ninety- nine righteous persons who do not need to repent. (NIV Luke 15:7-8)